# Installing up-to-date rails gem to gemfile reverts actionmailer back to version 0.6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, actionmailer, gemfile

I've been making a series of simple apps and I've been installing the same gems in my gemfile for each app the last few weeks and for some reason this time I've had some trouble.

When I `bundle` my Gemfile, then try to start the rails server or rails console I get the following error:

```
Aarons-iMac:ripelist AaronWilliamson$ rails s
/Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/ripelist/config/application.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_mailer/railtie (LoadError)
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/Desktop/ripelist/config/application.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/AaronWilliamson/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'email_validator'
gem 'devise'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'letter_opener'
end

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
    GIT
  remote: git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
  revision: 41da3a3c4c139964a9877c77220f94200d73c87a
  specs:
    paperclip (4.1.1)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.3)
      mime-types

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (0.6.1)
      actionpack (>= 0.9.5)
    actionpack (4.1.0)
      actionview (= 4.1.0)
      activesupport (= 4.1.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.0)
      activesupport (= 4.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.0)
      activesupport (= 4.1.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.0)
      activemodel (= 4.1.0)
      activesupport (= 4.1.0)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.7)
    better_errors (1.1.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.1.1.1)
      sass (~> 3.2)
    builder (3.2.2)
    capybara (2.2.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.4)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.2.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    email_validator (1.4.0)
      activemodel
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.0.2)
    factory_girl (4.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.4.1)
      factory_girl (~> 4.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.3.0)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.9)
    jquery-rails (3.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.1)
    launchy (2.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.2.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    mime-types (2.2)
    mini_portile (0.5.3)
    minitest (5.3.3)
    multi_json (1.9.3)
    nokogiri (1.6.1)
      mini_portile (~> 0.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    quiet_assets (1.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (0.9.5)
      actionmailer (>= 0.6.1)
      actionpack (>= 1.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 1.6.0)
      rake (>= 0.4.15)
    railties (4.1.0)
      actionpack (= 4.1.0)
      activesupport (= 4.1.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.1)
    rspec-core (2.14.8)
    rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
    rspec-rails (2.14.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
    sass (3.3.6)
    sass-rails (4.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
    shoulda-matchers (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sprockets (2.12.1)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.3)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.2.2)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.1.0)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    xpath (2.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bcrypt
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-sass
  capybara
  coffee-rails
  devise
  email_validator
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  jquery-rails
  launchy
  letter_opener
  paperclip!
  pg
  quiet_assets
  rails
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  shoulda-matchers
  turbolinks
  uglifier
```

config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Ripelist
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

My rails -v is 4.1.0
My ruby -v is ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

As a final note, when I run `bundle update`, nothing changes.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I've been tinkering for a few days now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to you `Gemfile.lock` you're using rails of version `0.9.5`.

Edit your `Gemfile` and change 3rd line to:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
```

then run `bundle update`